# SQL query to retrieve latest 20 records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table store the ID, User, Ranking and CreatedDate. The Ranking can be repeated. I would like to group up the Ranking 4 base on User and fetch the latest 20 record of Ranking 1,2,3 and 4.

Example of Table:

```
ID   User       Ranking     CreatedDate
----------------------------------------
1   B.Sisko       1st        1461136714  
2   B.Sisko       2nd        1461123378
3   B.Sisko       3rd        1461123378
4   B.Sisko       3rd        1461600137
5   K.Janeway     3rd        1461600137
6   K.Janeway     4th        1461602181
7   K.Janeway     4th        1461603096
8   J.Picard      3rd        1461603096
9   J.Picard      4th        1461603096
10  J.Picard      4th        1461603096
```

The result I want is:

```
ID   User       Ranking     CreatedDate
----------------------------------------
1   B.Sisko       1st        1461136714  
2   B.Sisko       2nd        1461123378
3   B.Sisko       3rd        1461123378
4   B.Sisko       3rd        1461600137
5   K.Janeway     3rd        1461600137
6   K.Janeway     4th        1461602181
7   J.Picard      3rd        1461603096
8   J.Picard      4th        1461603096
```

I want a query to able to retrieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `group up the Ranking 4 base on User` mean?  Nice use of Star Trek captain names, by the way.

Comment: How is your example different from your result? How does a record change its ID in the result (J Picard 3rd). This is just confusing.

Comment: And latest 20? Eh? There are only 10!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIMIT in SQL Server without some kind of third party add on, but the row number might work.

I'm not sure what should happen to the date, but here is an idea:

```
WITH cte_1 AS(
SELECT MIN(DATE) AS DATE
  , USER
  , RANK
FROM TABLE
WHERE RANK = 4
GROUP BY USER, RANK
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE
  , USER
  , RANK
FROM TABLE
WHERE RANK <> 4
),
cte_2 AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY USER, RANK) as run
FROM cte_1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_2
WHERE rank <= 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to `ORDER BY` both `USER` and `RANK`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY USER,RANK LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will retain a record if the `Ranking` be not equal to 4 *or* the `Ranking` is 4, but it has the earliest `CreatedDate` for that ranking.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Ranking, MIN(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Ranking
) t2
    ON t1.Ranking = t2.Ranking AND t1.CreatedDate = t2.CreatedDate
WHERE t1.Ranking <> '4th' OR (t1.Ranking = '4th' AND t2.Ranking IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Neither your comment nor question are clear to me.  I only answered because I love Star Trek :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I like your comments ;P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question yet, but try following;)

```
select *
from table1
where `Ranking` in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th')
group by
case `Ranking`
when '4th' then concat(`User`, `Ranking`)
else `ID` end
order by id
```

And [SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6f7a/4).

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be useful

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [USER],RANKING ORDER BY Ranking,CreatedDate) as RN, * FROM #T
)
,CTE1 AS (
SELECT * from CTE WHERE Ranking IN ('1st','2nd','3rd')
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ID,[User]
, Ranking 
,CreatedDate
FROM(
SELECT ID,[User]
, Ranking 
,CreatedDate
FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,[User]
, Ranking 
,CreatedDate
 FROM CTE 
WHERE RN =1 AND Ranking NOT IN ('1st','2nd','3rd')
) T
```